# MySQL format number with unknown number of decimal places

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In MySQL, I only want to add thousand separator in the number like 1234.23234, 242343.345345464, 232423.22 and format to "1,234.23234", "242,343.345345464", "232,423.22", use format function need to specify the number of decimals, is there any other function can format the number with unknown number of decimal places? for 1234.23234, I do not want to get the result like 1234.2323400000 or 1234.23, just want to get 1,234.23234.

Comment: It would be better to address the task of *data display* to the application that displays this data. Because numbers have no any format: 1,234.5 + 1 = 1234.5 + 1

Comment: what type is your data stored as?

Comment: MySQL doesn't seem to have such feature. You'll probably need to write a custom function based on `FORMAT()` plus some string manipulation to remove trailing zeroes after the comma.

Comment: try to alter your column, and set it to double. `Alter table yourtablename modify column yourcolumnName double(11,2)` the 11 inside the parenthesis is the max count of whole number while the 2 is the count of decimal places.

Comment: Set the number of decimal places which is obviously enough. Then apply `TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM {formatted value})` and remove excess zeros.

Comment: the data is input by user with unknown number of decimal places sometimes 2 decimal places, sometimes 4 decimal places (of course there is a limit for the number of decimal say max. 5 decimal places, user can freely input from 0 decimal place to 5 decimal places) and they need to see the exact number input with thousand separator.

Comment: what do you mean data is input by the user?  you are formatting data that is coming from your database, which originally came from the user, yes, but what type are you using to store it?

Comment: @ysth data is input by user, they input 1234 in the UI, then they would like to see 1,234 in the report, if they input 12345.2345 in the UI then they would like to see 12,345.2345 in the report. I store the data in VARCHAR (and please DO NOT ask why and DO NOT ask me to change the data type as it is not designed by me and I cannot change the data type) and I think the data type in VARCHAR or double doesn't matter, as I can cast the VARCHAR to double easily, my problem is the thousand separator with unknown number of decimal places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested split the string drop the trailing zeros format the number before the decimal point and concat taking into account the possibility of no decimals being present at all for example

```
set @a = 1234.56;

select 
case when instr(@a,'.') > 0 then
  concat(
  format(substring_index(@a,'.',1),'###,###,###'),
  '.',
  trim(trailing '0' from substring_index(@a,'.',-1))
  ) 
else
format (@a,'###,###,###')
end formatted
```

Comment: format's second parameter is a number of digits; supplying '###,###,###' gives a "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value" warning and is treated like 0.  But 0 is exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't seem to have such feature. You'll probably need to write a custom function based on [FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) plus some string manipulation to remove trailing zeroes after the comma, for example using [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace). The default locale used in `FORMAT()` is `en_US`, which seems to be the one you want, so you can omit it or provide your own should you need a different locale.

```
WITH sample_data (sample_number) AS (
    SELECT NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 0.00001
    UNION ALL SELECT 100.01
    UNION ALL SELECT 100.0102
    UNION ALL SELECT 100.012300456
    UNION ALL SELECT 1000
    UNION ALL SELECT 123456789.87654321
    UNION ALL SELECT -56500.333
)
SELECT
    sample_number,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        FORMAT(sample_number, 999),
        '(\.\\d*[1-9])(0+$)|(\.0+$)',
        '$1'
    ) AS USA,
    -- Replace \. with , for locales that use comma as decimal separator:
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        FORMAT(sample_number, 999, 'de_DE'),
        '(,\\d*[1-9])(0+$)|(,0+$)',
        '$1'
    ) AS Germany
FROM sample_data;
```

| sample_number | USA | Germany |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 0.000000000 | 0 | 0 |
| 0.000010000 | 0.00001 | 0,00001 |
| 100.010000000 | 100.01 | 100,01 |
| 100.010200000 | 100.0102 | 100,0102 |
| 100.012300456 | 100.012300456 | 100,012300456 |
| 1000.000000000 | 1,000 | 1.000 |
| 123456789.876543210 | 123,456,789.87654321 | 123.456.789,87654321 |
| -56500.333000000 | -56,500.333 | -56.500,333 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f611494d8069500b26974b1253539b34)